# SonarCloud Integration with Bitbucket not analysing C# files

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I have SonarCloud Integration with Bitbucket using Bitbucket pipelines but SonarCloud isn't analysing any of the .CS files.

I can see in the SonarCloud dashboard that it can see the files but doesn't analyse them.

It does scan some HTML and XML files so part of it is working.

Has anyone successfully got this to work or know what I could be doing wrong?

Cheers